# Changing Python Packages Path for Django Application

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, path, directory

I'm currently hosting with a dreamhost shared VPS. I do not have sudo rights. I want to install django packages but I cannot to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` because python is root access only. I have setup a directory in my user directory also called `dist-packages` to which I have copied all my packages to. I want to use the packages in the `dist-packages` directory I created to build my django app. Is possible to use my packages? I'm looking for a work around. I do have virtual python env installed, is there a way to use it maybe?

Python 2.7
Django 1.9

My current setup

```
/home/myuser/mydomain.com/
   env/
   myApp/
   passenger_wsgi.py
   public/
```

How do I setup the env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `virtualenv` for sure(I'm surprised that you are still looking for a work around). It's really inconvenient to use default python for everything. `virtualenv` will create an isolated python directory of your choice and install everything in there. When you want to use it, just "activate" it then you are automagically in that python environment.

It's almost trivial to learn how to create one, you can even create as many as you like, each with different packages installed. Check their [doc for more details](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Where do I put the dist-packages in the env?

Comment: virtualenv does that for you, you just `pip install whatever` after you activate your virtualenv. Again it's all in the isolated directory.

Comment: pip install worked after I activated it with source env/bin/activate Now where do I place my django app and env? My current setup is above.

Comment: You put your app anywhere you want. Since you have already activated your virtualenv the `dist-packages` directory is already in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: So my env is now my python path?

Comment: Right. That should be it.